# How to parse data from JSON request?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse specific parts of a JSON response using the OpenWeatherMap.org API and Python on a Raspberry Pi 3.  I am able to get the entire response using this script:

```
import requests
import json

settings = {
    'api_key':'my API key',
    'zip_code':'80550',
    'country_code':'us',
    'temp_unit':'imperial'} #unit can be metric, imperial, or kelvin

BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid={0}&zip={1},{2$

final_url = BASE_URL.format(settings["api_key"],settings["zip_code"],settings["$
weather_data = requests.get(final_url).json()

print(weather_data)
```

At this point I get the following:

```
{'coord': {'lon': -104.9, 'lat': 40.48}, 'weather': [{'id': 601, 'main': 'Snow', 'description': 'snow', 'icon': '13d'}, {'id': 701, 'main': 'Mist', 'description': 'mist', 'icon': '50d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 26.31, 'feels_like': 13.14, 'temp_min': 18, 'temp_max': 32, 'pressure': 1022, 'humidity': 86}, 'visibility': 3219, 'wind': {'speed': 14.99, 'deg': 30}, 'snow': {'1h': 0.64}, 'clouds': {'all': 100}, 'dt': 1587077009, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 4120, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1587039511, 'sunset': 1587087572}, 'timezone': -21600, 'id': 0, 'name': 'Windsor', 'cod': 200}
```

I would like to parse out data such as the "description" in the "weather" section of the response and store it in a variable but I keep running into various Type errors.  This seems like it should be a very simple process but I am struggling to find what must be an obvious answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `weather_data` is a dictionary. One of the keys of the dictionary, `description` points to a list of dictionaries. You need to look at each item in that list and pull out the `description`. The easiest way is with a list comprehension:

```
descriptions = [item['description'] for item in weather_data['weather']]
# ['snow', 'mist']
```

That will give you a new list with just the descriptions.

Comment: That allowed me to create an array of the data. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

```
obj = {'coord': {'lon': -104.9, 'lat': 40.48}, 'weather': [{'id': 601, 'main': 'Snow', 'description': 'snow', 'icon': '13d'}, {'id': 701, 'main': 'Mist', 'description': 'mist', 'icon': '50d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 26.31, 'feels_like': 13.14, 'temp_min': 18, 'temp_max': 32, 'pressure': 1022, 'humidity': 86}, 'visibility': 3219, 'wind': {'speed': 14.99, 'deg': 30}, 'snow': {'1h': 0.64}, 'clouds': {'all': 100}, 'dt': 1587077009, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 4120, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1587039511, 'sunset': 1587087572}, 'timezone': -21600, 'id': 0, 'name': 'Windsor', 'cod': 200}

for weather in obj['weather']:
    print(weather['description'])
```

prints

```
snow
mist
```